# Is there a way in Qliksense to set the first row of a given loaded dataset as header?

Tags: qliksense

So, basically, my dataset is looking like

| F1 | F2 | F3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Header 1 | Header2 | Header3 |
| -------- | --------- | --------- |

My goal is to use the PowerBI function that sets the first row as header but I'm not finding a way to do it in Qliksense. Does anyone know how I can get this done? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `Embedded field names` is selected when loading the data:

[image: Embedded field names]

If its `No field names` then the field names will be "auto-generated"

[image: No field names]

(Hope that ive understand the question correctly)